# Paramiko uploading file successfully but it's empty

Tags: python, pandas, sftp, paramiko

Trying to export a dataframe to csv using StringIO and transfer it via SFTP using paramiko. The file comes through successfully but it's empty. Any idea why?

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import paramiko

names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]

BabyDataSet = list(zip(names,births))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])

buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf, sep = ',', header = True, index = False)
#buf.getvalue() # Correct output

transport = paramiko.Transport(('localhost', 22))
transport.connect(username='user', password='pass')
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

upload_path = '/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv'
sftp.putfo(buf, upload_path)
sftp.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this line, you have written to `buf` as though it's a file.

```
df.to_csv(buf, sep = ',', header = True, index = False)
```

It's a file-like object, so it has a reference to how far through that 'file' you are. When `putfo` tries to read from `buf` it will read from the last place used, and since you've written to the buffer, that location is at the end of your data. `buf.getvalue()` returns the *entire* contents of the buffer, regardless of the current position in the file. Seek to the start to get everything when reading normally:

```
df.to_csv(buf, sep = ',', header = True, index = False)
buf.seek(0) # rewind to the beginning of the 'file'
sftp.putfo(buf, upload_path)
```